# React filter 'state' undefined

Tags: reactjs, jsx, axios

So I started using reactjs and I've managed to loop through some XML data but having issues adding a search/filter into it.

This is my code so far:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import XMLMapping from 'xml-mapping';
import axios from 'axios';

class Guests extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        guests: [],
        search: 'Search Guests'
    };
 }

componentDidMount() {
  axios.get('http://localhost:8080/guestlist.xml')
  .then(res => {
    const xml = XMLMapping.load(res.data);
    var guests  = XMLMapping.tojson(xml);
    this.setState({guests: guests});
    //console.log(guests);
    return guests;
  });
}
updateSearch(event) {
  this.setState({
    // Limit to 10 characters only for search
    search: event.target.value.substr(0, 10)
  });
  //    console.log(this.state.search); // this will show the previous value of state.
}
  render() {
    function mapObject(object, callback) {
      return Object.keys(object).map(function (key) {
        return callback(key, object[key]);
      });
    }
    const firstname = mapObject(this.state.guests, function (key, value) {
      return <div key={key}>
        {value.record
        .map((item,index) => {
          //console.log(index)
          return <div className="columns" key={index}>
            <div className="column" key={index}>{item.first_name.$t} {item.last_name.$t}</div> 
            <div className="column" >{item.company.$t}</div>
          </div>;
        })}
        </div>
      });
      let filteredGuests = mapObject(this.state.guests, function (key, value) {
        value.record.filter(
          (contact) => {
            return contact.first_name.$t.indexOf(this.state.search) !== -1;
            //console.log(this.state.search)
          }
        );
      });
    return (
      <div>
          <div className="container">
                <section className="section">
                    <h1 className="title">Guests attending Event A</h1> <input className="text" type="text" value={this.state.search} onChange={this.updateSearch.bind(this)} /> 
                    <div className="columns"><div className="column">Name</div><div className="column">Company</div></div>             
                          {firstname}
                </section>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Guests;
```

But it seems to be throwing an error TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined

This is the line `return contact.first_name.$t.indexOf(this.state.search) !== -1;`

Any advice or feedback would be appreciate!

Comment: Do you mean this.state.search.bind(this)? I tried that and that didn’t work @LJ

Comment: Try converting `filteredGuests` callback `function (key, value) {` to arrow function like `(key, value) => {`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As **Prakash sharma** wrote, you used the wrong function context.

Try to replace `function` with arrow function:

```
let filteredGuests = mapObject(this.state.guests, (key, value) => {
  value.record.filter(
    (contact) => {
      return contact.first_name.$t.indexOf(this.state.search) !== -1;
      //console.log(this.state.search)
    }
  );
})
```

Comment: i would recommend to avoid creating a function instances inside the render method

Comment: But the search functionality isn't working.. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: Managed to get it to work added the filter() to value.record instead. Thanks :)

Comment: @Sag1v you're right, but actually here it would be a premature optimization. In general you're absolutely right

Comment: Where should the functions go @Sag1v?

Comment: @msbodetti he means that the "best practices" is to keep `render` method as simple as possible. So if you create a function inside `render` it will be better to move it outside that method (like another method of the class or even outside the class), but I'll not suggest you to do it before you came across real performance problems

Comment: Oh I see, thanks @havenchyk. I moved it outside of the class and it works. Will look into creating extended classes for these types of functions.